# Setting a browser cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, cordova, express, session-cookies

**My problem:** My browser isn't getting the session cookie set. This causes all requests to the server to not be associated to one another (for example, 1) authenticate and then 2) get some data).

**Background/Context:**

I'm building a product that has a mobile and web side to it. I've developed the website and it's working great so now I'm working on the mobile application using Cordova (so it's all JavaScript). I want to use the same backend for the mobile app as I do for the website.

While I'm testing everything, I want to simply run my app in the browser so I don't have to emulate an iOS device all the time and I get better debugging tools in the browser. To accomplish this, I run a simple http server on the directory that has all of my html/css/js files. Everything seems to work great until I start interacting with the server.

**My Setup**:

The server is running on localhost:3000. The cordova app is being served up on localhost:3001. When the mobile app loads, the first thing it does is hit `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/isAuthenticated` which returns `{isAuthenticated: true|false}`. What the endpoint does is irrelevant. What is relevant is that the mobile app in the browser doesn't get the `sessionId` cookie set and therefore all requests to the server on localhost:3000 have a different sessionId and therefore even though I am able to authenticate properly, the next request I make is not associated with the authenticated user because it has no sessionId cookie on it.

**My question:** What is a good way to solve this problem? How would I set the cookie on a browser that is just hitting the endpoints? Should I instead use something like [oauth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) and do some sort of token exchange?

**Other interesting notes:**

- I'm using express.js sessions. I have actually tried this with both the latest 3.x version and release candidate for 4.x. Neither did the trick.
- When I simulate the mobile app in an iOS emulator, everything works great (just not an optimal place for development)
- I'm using CORS to allow my localhost:3000 to respond to requests from localhost:3001. Requests are working, it's just the cookie not getting set is the problem.
- The [platypus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus) is the only mammal which lays eggs instead of giving birth :)

Thanks!

Comment: So your question is basically why aren't cookies being set in the mobile browser?  Can we see the code that's supposed to set the cookie?

Comment: @AlexMA, actually it's not working in an actual browser on the desktop, that's where I'm having trouble. The cookie setting logic is in a [black box](https://github.com/expressjs/session). But I'm thinking that I may not be using the black box correctly.

Comment: Perhaps try setting some simple non-session cookies with the npm module "cookies".  Should only take a moment to check whether cookies are working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a security issue. Server's are not allowed to set cookies on browsers from other domains. So the industry has come up with a solution: [JSON Web Tokens](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html). I implemented this after an hour or two and it seems to be working great.

Comment: P.S. I have actually since created [a screencast series](https://egghead.io/series/angularjs-authentication-with-jwt) on [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/) about this concept if you're interested :-)